# Multiple vs single database

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, database-design

We are developing a new version of our web application. 
We have multiple clients (500+), each client has its own database with its own data: users, products...

In the new version, all clients are going to share some data, for example, users are going to be in the platform but each client will be able to access to their users only, but instead of having the users for each client we want to have all the users in a centralize table.

Other things such as products, orders...are going to belong to each client.

Each client will have a copy of the web app installed in their domain.
Our app is an ASP MVC Entity Framework Code First, using SQL Server.

Our question is:

- Option A: One database per client containing their tables (products, orders...) and one common database to store the users and other common data.
- Option B: One big database containing all and add a ClientId to certain tables so the clients only see their data.

PROS AND CONS:

- With Option A we have several databases, we can have 100.000 orders in a table and it is easy to retrieve that data. On the other hand we have to deal with cross database queries and having 2 Data Context. This is the prolem, beacuse we need to retrieve user data for most of the queries, that means access to both databases, the client specific and the common one.
- With option B we just have to deal with 1 context and the queries are much more simple. The main concern for this approach is we could have some tables with more than 10.000 records per year, per client. So in 10 years, with 500 clients, we could have a table with 50 millions records and this could affect performance.

Thanks for your advices.

EDIT

The thing here is not a question abou single vs multiple database because we have one more thing in the game, all clients need to access a common database.

EDIT 2

Let's say we have decided to go for a single database for all our clients. So we will have multiple domains, each one with our application running, but we need each of them getting only their data.

How can we do this? Adding a ClientId to each table and filtering the data with a parameter "clientId" in the web.config of each site?

Comment: Are you using an on premises SQL Server at each client site currently? With one central database you'd have to consider network latency. Along this line, are they all geographically close? Security's going to be a big concern for you.

Comment: To mitigate your concerns for Option B you could partition the tables

Comment: at this time all of the databases are on the same server...the only thing that is having us thinking is we now need common users for all the clients since we are developing a global platform

Comment: To solve the multi context issue you can just use a synonym or view in the client database that references the central database. Cross database references can cause headaches but if you plan it into your architecture it's not a problem

Comment: If the common things are primarily users and permissions you might want to consider a different platform for that i.e. some incarnation of AD. Whether thats on premise, or azure

Comment: We have to use EF Code First...so, how to create synonyms using code first? ALso  I asume you prefer the multiple database with one common (n+1 databases) rather thna a big one

Comment: Whether you use n+1 or 1 databases depends on a lot of things - my suggestion might help you decide either way. I don't think you can do anything cross database with code first. You're _really_ limiting yourself there. I think you're probably limited to one database only in that case

Comment: Well, my main, and maybe only, concern about one big database is performance due to size of tables and database. The rest of cons for us I think are pros,

Comment: There are many performance objects you can use such as table partitioning and indexing. But again these can't be defined from code first.

Comment: You mean to get better performance...yes, I know, we have to define that in the database server. I have seen one approach to do this using code first is, as you mentioned,  synonyms pointing to the common database. That would work for us...

Comment: If you find a way to use synonyms with code first please do post. It doesn't seem to align with the 'single dbcontext' approach (because the synonym needs to contain a different 'unknown' database name in it). If you are tied to the 'Visual Studio deployment' approach rather than just the code first approach then a lot of options are opened up with VS database projects. You should be able to create synonyms and indexes by using that.

Answer (score 0):

My personal preference would be for option A, and the primary reason would be for security. You basically have only a couple of points of failure for leaking one client's data to another.

You could look to put a service on top of the common data and cache frequent requests for user data to handle that side of things.

Comment: Our main thing here is we do need a common database to store all the users and other common things, and most of the queries will have to query that database since we need the users info. Also all clients could update those users, so everyone gets the update. Our main problem is managing that in EF Code Firs Context, since we need 2 contexts and the queries are complicated, losing some of the advantages of EF

Answer (score 0):

Option A would be the recommended approach as that will allow all different clients to query on their own selected transactional records and without any performance issues because of the requests from other clients.

Also, the option A would allow the entities based customization (if required in future) which would prove to be a challenge with option B. Multi-tenant based architecture is the recommendation.

The below mentioned resource can help you with some more options/possibilities.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479086.aspx

Comment: do you think we could have more performance issues with one database than with multiple databases in the same server?

Comment: We won't do customization per client in the future, this is a software package. Our main problem is all the clients have common data such as users, even if a user is created in a client it'd be stored in the common database

Comment: You can host multiple databases on the same physical server and SQL server can be configured in more detailed settings for optimum performance. One master database can store the users which will be shared across all different databases as per the software functional requirements and still get the best optimization with shared and separate client databases.

Comment: thanks for the page, it is a very interesting article. I'm moving between the shared db and separate db. Some pros and cons...I'd prefer separate databases but the context problem we have on EF code first is making me doubt....